# aspx page with AjaxControlTolKit not working in server but works with local

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

For one of my aspx page in my application. I am using `ajaxcontroltoolkit` and when I deploy this in my server it throws the below error for that page alone. I also imported the `ddl` to my project and deployed it, but no luck.

Can anyone suggest me some alternate solutions.?

[image: Image Screenshot for error]

Comment: which version of `Ajax control toolkit` are you using. Please specify

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `AjaxControlToolkit` dll is either on the server in the GAC or in the application `/bin` directory.

You can do this by installing the `AjaxControlToolkit` on the server, or by setting **CopyToLocal** to `true` in for the reference in the project.

In the **Solution Explorer** goto **Solution** > **Project** > **References**, right click **AjaxControlToolKit** and click Properties and set the **CopyToLocal** field to `true`.

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit is present in server also I have set CopyToLocal to true.

Comment: That message is a result of either the ACT not being on the server or something it relies on.